# weird usage of "dran"

Tags: preposition, adverb

I know it means multiple somethings like:

1. Du bist dran!: You're next!
2. as a shortened version of "daran".

But I have encountered this sentence:

> Meistens bin ich mit der Vorbereitung der Prüfung spät **dran** und kann mir dann nicht mehr alles merken.

I can't see any meaning for "dran" here. What is it doing in this sentence??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"dran" or "daran" usually references some subject, state or location which was mentioned in a previous sentence. For example:

> "Michael hat seinen Termin verpasst. **Daran** bin nur ich schuld."
> "Michael missed his appointment. **That** is completely my fault."

> "Täglich wird es wärmer. **Daran** erkennt man, dass der Frühling kommt."
> "It is getting warmer every day. **This** is how you can tell that spring is coming."

> "Die Tür ist wackelig. Lehne dich bitte nicht **daran** an."
> "The door is wobbly. Please don't lean against **it**."

Now, for the sentence "Du bist **dran**." there is no direct noun that is being referenced here. But since this is somewhat of a set phrase, "dran" implicitly refers to "die Reihe"/"the queue" or "the line" (either a physical or metaphorical one). So actually it means

> "Du bist **an der Reihe**"
> "You're next (in line)"

as you correctly translated.

Moving to your actual question, let's look at the problematic sentence again:

> "Meistens bin ich mit der Vorbereitung der Prüfung spät dran und kann mir dann nicht mehr alles merken."
> "Usually I am late for preparations for the exam and then I can no longer remember everything."

"mit etw. spät dran sein"/"to be late for smth." is a set phrase, but the "dran" always refers to the "etw."/"smth." that comes before it. In this case, the "dran" is connected to the thing you're doing, i.e. the "Vorbereitung der Prüfung".

Comment: Nice exposition! (+1) I remember one more use in a 1700 years in a rebellion-song "Drauf und dran, setzt auf's Klosterdach den roten Hahn". Here "dran" has one more, today surely forgotten, meaning.

Answer (score 17):

The phrase *spät dran sein* means *to be running late*. It is a fixed word combination.

**Update:**

As Arsak comments, *spät dran sein* has *früh dran sein* as a counterpart.

Comment: Might be worth to add that *früh dran sein* (to be early) is used as well.